# How do I raise and handle Signals?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, kill

Within a process, if I want to send signals for a specific thread and handle it,
I have several options like `kill()`, `pthread_kill()`, `tkill()`, `sigqueue()`.

Among these, which will guarantee that the signal is delivered to the specified thread only, and that to each time signal is raised periodically. And what would be the limitations?

Comment: My personal opinion is that you should only use signals for extraordinary situations and the signal handling code should be simple as you do not know where it has occurred. Your best bet is to rework your solution to take into account of the periodic activity.

Comment: i want to run a my function in the context of each thread periodically.. and i dont find any function which would do that other than Signal Handler.. so after raising a Signal for the Thread, i will wait for Signal Handler to finish its work...

Comment: Be aware that signal handlers can only call a restricted class of functions (the async-safe ones; read `man 7 signal` for more).

Comment: @sandeep - Instead of signal handling use mutual exclusion etc. See http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads